# Stored objects in a vector, when are they being destroyed?

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

Working on a small role-playing game battle system to practice object-oriented code. I have a Party class, which has a vector to store a variable amount of party members.

Initializing my party and adding a member seems to work great. I'm even able to call the member's take_damage() function to change the member's hp and that seems to work too.

But when I check on the same member's hp on the next line using the hp getter, it's right back where it started.

I made a destructor for the member class to see what was going on and according to the output the object is being destroyed many times. Why is this?

```
class Member
{
private:
    int hp;

public:
    Member() { hp = 1; }
    ~Member() { std::cout << "DESTROYED!!" << std::endl; }
    int get_hp() { return hp; }
    void take_damage(int amt) { hp += amt }
};

class Party {
private:
    std::vector<Member> members;

public:
    void add_member(Member memb) { members.push_back(memb); }
    Member get_member(int num) { return members[num]; }
};

int main() {
    Party p;
    Member m;

    p.add_member(m);

    std::cout << p.get_member(0).get_hp() << std::endl;
    p.get_member(0).take_damage(4);
    std::cout << p.get_member(0).get_hp() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your get_member method returns a *copy* of the array element, rather than a reference to it. Return a reference, and the member will be modified.

```cpp
Member& get_member(int num) { return members[num]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

see small issue in code `-=amt`
also changed function of get_member

other than that, the code seems fine.

```
class Member
{
private:
    int hp;

public:
    Member() { hp = 1; }
    ~Member() { std::cout << "DESTROYED!!" << std::endl; }
    int get_hp() { return hp; }
    void take_damage(int amt) { hp -= amt } // This should be -=amt, not +=amt
};

class Party {
private:
    std::vector<Member> members;

public:
    void add_member(Member memb) { members.push_back(memb); }
    Member& get_member(int num) { return members[num]; }
};

int main() {
    Party p;
    Member m;

    p.add_member(m);

    std::cout << p.get_member(0).get_hp() << std::endl;
    p.get_member(0).take_damage(4);
    std::cout << p.get_member(0).get_hp() << std::endl;
}
```